# Unable to install Sybase Client on Windows 2012 Server R2

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sap-iq

I am trying to install Sybase client version 16.0 on Windows 2012 Server R2 (64-bit OS,x-64 based processor), but am getting the following error while running the set up file:

> ```
> Fatal Application Error: This Application has Unexpectedly Quit 
> Invocation of this Java application has cause an Invocation Target
> Exception.this application will now exit (LAX)
>
> Application Exception Details: ZeroGu6: Windows DLL failed to load
>  at ZeroGa4.b(DashoA10*..)  at ZeroGa4.b(DashoA10*..)
>  at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.b(DashoA10*..)
>  at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a(DashoA10*..)
>  at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(DashoA10*..)
>  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>  at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA10*..)
>  at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA10*..)
> ```

I have tried the solutions available online but none of seems to be working, like running as administrator with windows 7 compatibility, Installing C++ Redistributable package  Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64) and Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package (x64).

Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: where did you get your installation file from? what is the name of the installation file? what command(s) have you executed in an attempt to install the software?

Comment: I got the installation file from another person who had downloaded it from SAP marketplace. the file name is setup.exe which is under "pcclient64" folder and i am running the setup as an administrator (rightclick>run as administrator)

Answer (score 0):

Cause
This is a Windows Compatibility issue.

Resolution

1 Right mouse click on the setup.exe or setupconsole.exe and select Properties. 
2 Select the Compatibility tab. 
3 Under Compatiblity mode, select the checkbox next to 'Run this program in compatibility mode for:'.

Make sure the dropdownlistbox shows Windows 7

4 Click Apply. 
5 Click OK.

Comment: Like i mentioned i tried these solutions which were available online.. but does not work for me. On running with Windows 7 compatibility mode, i don't see the mentioned error, but there is no installation wizard for sybase client, basically nothing happens.

Comment: I checked the support matrix for SAP SDK 16.0. I found it missing Windows 2012 R2 as an approved platform. Windows 2012 R2 is listed as an approved platform for standalone ASE

Answer (score 0):

In order not to run into these errors, refer to the target OS compatibility matrix.

Choosing the correct product version eliminated these issues for the installations conducted on my end.